# It seems that I have problem understanding that convergence in mean implying convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

From various sources (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables)), I read convergence in mean implies convergence in probability. However, I have some examples that seem to disagree with this statement.

Let $X^{(1)}$ and $X^{(2)}$ be two distinct ($X^{(1)} \ne X^{(2)}$) standard normal random variables. Let $U$ and $V$ be two random variables with bounded means. Then define $Z_n^{(1)}:=X^{(1)}+U/n$ and $Z_n^{(2)}:=X^{(2)}+V/n$.

Apparently $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[|Z_n^{(1)}-Z_n^{(2)}|]=0$ but 
$Z_n^{(1)} \not\rightarrow _p Z_n^{(2)}$, since $X^{(1)} \ne X^{(2)}$.

I'm sure I'm stupidly wrong but could some one let me know where did I make the mistake exactly.

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathbb{E}[|Z_n^{(1)} - Z_n^{(2)}|] \to 0$?

Comment: $Z_n^{(1)} \not\rightarrow _p Z_n^{(2)}$ makes no sense.

Comment: It looks to me $\lim_{n\to \infty}E|Z_n^1-Z_n^2|=E|X^{(1)}-X^{(2)}|$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, good one! How about if I say $U>V$ and $X^{(1)}>X^{(2)}$ so the absolute value becomes irrelavent.

Comment: @yellowlm  : If $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same (finite) mean and satisfy $X_1 \geq X_2$, then 
$X_1 = X_2$ with prob 1. This is because $$ 0 = E[X_1-X_2] = E[|X_1-X_2|] \geq \epsilon P[|X_1-X_2|\geq \epsilon]$$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: @Michael This seems a bit unintuitive to me. Any reference? Let's say we generate two standard normal here and give the larger one to $Z^{(1)}_n$.

Comment: In my chain of equalities above: The first equality uses the "same mean" assumption, the second equality uses $X_1 - X_2 = |X_1-X_2|$, the third inequality is Markov's inequality for nonnegative random variables. The conclusion is that $P[|X_1-X_2|\geq \epsilon] = 0$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Note also that if $Y=\max[A,B]$, where $A$ and $B$ are iid standard normal, the random variable $Y$ is _not_ standard normal, and the mean of $Y$ is generally larger than 0.

Comment: @Michael OK, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not careful enough with absolute values:
$|E(X)|$ and $E(|X|)$ are very different things. In general the latter is larger than or equal to the former.

$E(|X|)$ being small is a very strong condition. In your case what you have is 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\mathbb{E}[Z_n^{(1)}-Z_n^{(2)}]|=0$$ but there is no way to take the absolute values inside, unless, precisely, if $P(X^{(1)}=X^{(2)})=1$.

Comment: Ok yes, my bad. But how about if I enforce $U>V$ and $X^{(1)}>X^{(2)}$

Comment: @yellowlm It's the same.  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[|Z_n^{(1)}-Z_n^{(2)}|]=\mathbb{E}[|X^{(1)}-X^{(2)}|]$ and that is again $0$ if and only if $P(X^{(1)}=X^{(2)})=1$.